# IE bug triggers click for 2 buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, internet-explorer, jquery-events

I am trying to trigger the submit button when a user presses <kbd>enter</kbd>. Works great for all browsers except Internet Explorer 9. Strange thing is that IE insists on also triggering the click for another button I never told it to. Am I doing something wrong or how to fix this?

Below is my code. Pressing enter in IE triggers the submit click as expected, but for some reason also triggers the "some button" click (even without my keypress listener):

```
$('input[type=submit]').click(function () {
    alert('Submit click');
});

//SIMULATE CLICK IF ENTER PRESSED IN SEARCH
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == 13) $('input[type=submit]').click();
});

//ROUTE CLEAR HANDLER
$('button').click(function () {
    alert('Button click');
});
```

You can see the bug in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/h64xD/

Comment: Isn't submitting when pressing Enter in an input field standard behaviour?

Comment: @Bergi that is true if you consider the `input` field as part of the same `form` as the `button`, and also that the `button` has to be of `type="submit"` to be triggered as default action.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Here are a couple of things to consider:

IE9 counts the `<button/>` element as `type="submit"` by default. So to make it non-submit, you have to be explicit:

```
<button type="button">Some button</button>
```

If you do that, you will notice that the emulated `click` event now doesn't trigger the `<button/>` but still fires 2 events. The reason is that, because you haven't explicitly defined a `<form/>` element, IE9 assumes the controls as being in a form, and thus pressing `enter` in the textbox triggers 2 events:

- the one that you are emulating
- the default form submit button behaviour

So again to get around this issue, you have to be explicit:

```
<button type="button">Some button</button>
<form><input type="text" /></form>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Now, these are the reasons that you are seeing the behaviour in IE. [@MrSlayer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10739803/476786)'s answer caters to the second issue of stopping the `keypress` event after you have satisfactorily handled it, using `preventDefault()`

Answer (score 5):

The Enter key has a default behavior to submit, so you need to prevent the default behavior from executing.  Because the `button` tag is, by default, `type="submit"` it is executing that button when the Enter key is pressed.

```
//SIMULATE CLICK IF ENTER PRESSED IN SEARCH
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function (event) {
    var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which;
    if (keycode == 13)
    {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input[type=submit]').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about triggering the form's submit instead of a button click?

```
$('input[type=text]').keypress(function(e) {
     var keycode = event.keyCode || event.which,
         frm = $(this).closest('form');

     if (keycode == 13) {
          e.stopPropagation();
          frm.submit();
          return false;
     }
     return true;
});
```

--EDIT--

Updated Slightly to stop the event propagation.

Comment: Don't use `$(this).closest('form')` but just `this.form`

Answer (score 1):

First off, you don't need to manually attach an event to submit a form when the user presses <kbd>enter</kbd> - the browser already handles that.

Oddly enough, this was to do with the order of the elements, implicit form-associations, as well as the fact that IE handles buttons as submit elements.

Try swapping the order of these buttons to see what I mean:

```
<input type="text" />
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
<button>Some button</button>
```

Naturally, the browser is already instructed to listen to respond to the <kbd>Enter</kbd> on a text-input. This results in the browser *clicking* the associated submit button. Further, since you haven't explicitly provided a `form`, or associated elements with one another via their `form` attribute, the browser is attempting to make that relationship for you.

In your code, the `<button>` element was assumed to be the submit button of the text-input (because it was the first submit button in the implicit form). As such, anytime you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the text-input, the browser naturally raises the click event of the associated button.

If you re-order the elements, as I have above, we see the opposite take place. IE associates the other `<input>` element with the text-box. And pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> on the text-box implicitly raises the click event on the submit input.

You can confirm this behavior by comparing the `.form` attributes of various elements. For instance, adding some `id` values will give us easier access to these:

```
<button id="fiz">Some Button</button>
<input  id="foo" type="text" />
<input  id="bar" type="submit" value="Submit" />
```

Then run some quick comparisons:

```
var button = document.getElementById("fiz"); 
var text = document.getElementById("foo"); 
var submit = document.getElementById("bar"); 

button.form === text.form;   // true 
submit.form === text.form;   // true 
button.form === submit.form; // true
```

So in the end, it's up to you to remove the ambiguity between the two buttons, by declaring the `<button>` element to be `type='button'`, or by placing it after the intended submit button.

Comment: Hi, how different is your answer than the one I posted? Yes you have reordered the elements, which IS a factor in how submits happen, but that changes the page layout. It is a great answer if OP is conceptually interested in the issue, but not otherwise, because you can get around the issue without changing UI.

Comment: @bPratik The OP asked about the nature of the behavior. I'm answering.